# Scheme help - how to call a function

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, evaluate, function-call

I'm new to Scheme, and I am trying to manipulate a list and return the cdr of a pair in the list.

So far here is my code:

```
(define get-userid (lambda (ls)
  (if (pair? ls)
      (cdar ls)
      (get-userid (cdar ls)))))
```

**The list I wish to manipulate is:**

```
(define *rider-preferences4*
  '((userid . anna)
    (role . rider)
    (origin . "southampton")
    (destination . "glasgow")
    (time . "15:15")
    (capacity . 2)
    (smoking . no)))
```

Input and outputs:

```
> get-userid *rider-preferences4*
#<procedure:get-userid>
((userid . anna) (role . rider) (origin . "southampton") (destination . "glasgow") (time . "15:15") (capacity . 2) (smoking . no))
> get-userid (get-userid *rider-preferences4*)
#<procedure:get-userid>
**anna**
```

I want the result of just `anna`, and to be able to do it just by calling `get-userid`. How would this be possible? Even though I assume it's trivial.

Comment: Does the code as it appears in your question look the way it's supposed to?  You may want to take a look at the formatting guide, [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `*rider-preferences4*` is an association list you can use the specific [procedures](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=assoc#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._assoc%29%29)  (`assoc`, `assq`, `assv`) to retrieve any key:

```
> (cdr (assq 'userid *rider-preferences4*))
'anna
> (cdr (assq 'destination *rider-preferences4*))
"glasgow"
```

so the code is

```
(define (get-userid alst)
  (cdr (assq 'userid alst)))
```

Besides being usable for any key, it is also independent of the position, so

```
> (get-userid '((role . rider) (userid . anna)))
'anna
```

will also work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're a bit confused with the way list operations work in Scheme, I suggest you take a look at the relevant section in the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html). For this problem, the solution is as simple as this:

```
(define get-userid ; even simpler: (define get-userid cdar)
  (lambda (ls)
    (cdar ls)))
```

Explanation: the input list is a list of pairs, and we're interested in the `cdr` part of the first element (which holds the user id). So we take the `cdr` of the `car`, or abbreviated: the `cdar`. It works as expected:

```
(get-userid *rider-preferences4*)
=> 'anna
```